# Why does my JavaScript still load before my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've tried all the recommended solutions: moving my script after `<body>` element; inserting right before closing `<body>` tag; wrapping all my JS code in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {})`, yet I still get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at HTMLDocument. (script.js:245:9)
(anonymous) @ script.js:245**

What am I still doing wrong? Currently, my JS/HTML is as follows:

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
/* LAYOUT.HTML */
  console.log("Welcome to my JavaScript!");
...
};
```

**HTML**

```
...
  <div class="flex-1">
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </div>

      <div class="space-y-1 w-full">
        <div class="bg-white w-full xyz-in" style="height: 1px" xyz="right-100% duration-10"></div>
        <div class="bg-white w-full xyz-in" style="height: 2px" xyz="right-100% duration-20"></div>
        <div class="bg-white w-full xyz-in" style="height: 3px" xyz="right-100% duration-30"></div>
        <div class="flex relative bg-white w-full h-24 items-center justify-center">
          <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-20 object-contain"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/script.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
 
</html>
```

**JS Code Creating Error**

```
// First Name & Last Name Validation
  let ABC = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

  let fname = document.getElementById("fname");

  fname.addEventListener("input", () => ABCvalidate(fname));

  let lname = document.getElementById("lname");

  lname.addEventListener("input", () => ABCvalidate(lname));

  function ABCvalidate(name) {
    const errorElement = document.getElementById("CSerror");
    if (!ABC.test(name.value)) {
      errorElement.innerHTML =
        "No spaces, numbers, or special characters allowed";
    } else {
      errorElement.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
```

**HTML extended in {% block body %}, containing my elements**

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
  <div
    class="bg-white border-4 border-solid border-gray-300 rounded-md w-2/3 mx-auto mb-4 px-2 py-2 md:w-1/4"
  >
    <label for="fname" class="font-bold">First Name</label>
    <input
      type="input"
      placeholder="Enter your first name..."
      id="fname"
      name="fname"
      required
      class="placeholder-gray-500 border-2 border-solid border-gray-300 bg-gray-200 rounded-md w-full pl-1 mb-2"
    />

    <label for="lname" class="font-bold">Last Name</label>
    <input
      type="input"
      placeholder="Enter your last name..."
      id="lname"
      name="lname"
      required
      class="placeholder-gray-500 border-2 border-solid border-gray-300 bg-gray-200 rounded-md w-full pl-1 mb-2"
    />
```

Comment: There is no element in your HTML, that has the id "fname" or "lname". That is why you get the error.

Comment: Hi Geshode, there is - for sake of brevity, the HTML you're seeing is the end of my layout HTML  to show where I've placed the <script>; the element w/ id "fname" or "lname" is extended within {% block body %}{% endblock %} in another html file

Comment: In the error message it says there is something that is `null` at line 245. Since we don't have your line numbers, which JS variable is being accessed on that line?

Comment: A `null` error very commonly means that a `.getElementById()` call has not found an element, and it then returns `null`.  Your code does not verify that the calls to find elements have actually returned a real reference (and not `null`), so that is the most likely problem.

Answer (score 0):

All,

I've learned the issue had to do with what HTML page I was loading while running the `.getElementbyId()` method; because I was not loading the appropriate HTML page which corresponds to the JS, my code was not able to find the element.

I incorrectly thought that `document.getElementbyId()` scans across all HTML pages of your website, thus necessitating the need for unique IDs - I've further learned that you can use the same ID for different elements so long as those elements are in different HTML files.

See below for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById